# Pydev Console is very slow

Tags: pydev, eclipse-cdt

When I open a pydev console, it takes several seconds before I get a cursor. I have a single file "Hello World" sort of project. There are no large variables to show. 
My installation used Kepler-CDT, and I then installed PyDev (Latest, version 3.6.0)

I right select the console icon, select New PyDev Console, and then the console selection dialog appears. I select "Python console" (OK).

"Create Interactive Console" shows in the eclipse progress bar. Eventually, IPython starts, and after 20 seconds or so, I get a >>> prompt.

If I press enter at the prompt, another prompt appears as expected, but it usually take 4 or 5 seconds.

Some suggestions I have seen talk about firewall issues, how would I go about checking this?

How do I debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your OS? From what you're saying, the issue really 'appears' to be either some network misconfiguration or possibly some firewall/antivirus making things slower (you can try disabling those to test if things go faster). As for a network misconfiguration, you can try checking your hosts file to see if things are correct there (I've had reports where there were other things, but these are the most common -- for other situations it may be more difficult to diagnose as usually each particular case is something different).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm running Windows 7. I disconnected a USB-Ethernet adapter, and everything started working wayyyy faster. The adapter was going to a switch, and nothing else. If I set things up to use that adapter again, I'll diagnose further at that point. Thanks again, you pointed me in the right direction.